# h:inputText value not set in bean

Tags: jsf

The `<h:inputText>` value is not been set in a request scoped bean. If the value is preserved from DB, it works fine.

view:

```
<h:inputText id="receipient" size="90" styleClass="text" readonly="#{!bean.enable}" value="#{bean.recipient}" />
```

bean:

```
public class Bean {
    private String recipient;
    Bean(){
        recipient = //load from db
    }
    //set 
    //get
}
```

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `readonly="#{!bean.enable}"` evaluates the same as it was in initial view. If it evaluates `true` during apply request values phase of the form submit, then the component's value won't be processed (because it is marked as read only).

An easy test is to put the bean in session scope. If that fixes it, then you know the culprit. If you're using JSF 2.0, just put bean in view scope by using `@ViewScoped` instead of `@RequestScoped`. If you're still on JSF 1.x, use [Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_saveState.html) component to let the bean act like the JSF 2.0 view scoped one.

```
<t:saveState value="#{bean}" />
```

Comment: Hi Balu,
Thank you for reply.
Can please give example for one text field with saveState?

Comment: Just reference the value which you'd like to retain in subsequent request. `<t:saveState value="#{bean.value}" />`